# How can I find the values that repeat themselves consecutively at least 3 times using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am looking for the values that repeat themselves at least three times on a sequentially sorted table by an increasing ID.

For example:

| Sequential | Code |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 2301 |
| 02 | 1909 |
| 03 | 3310 |
| 04 | 3310 |
| 05 | 3310 |
| 06 | 2300 |
| 07 | 1999 |

In this case, I would need the output to be

| Code |
| --- |
| 3310 |

As this is the only code that repeats itself three times **consecutively** (note that the code might repeat itself many times in the table, but if it's not consecutive, it doesn't meet the condition.

How can I do this using PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a gaps and islands problem.  You are asking which island of code records occurs three at a time.  We can use the difference in row numbers method here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Sequential) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY Sequential) rn2
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT DISTINCT Code
FROM cte
GROUP BY (rn1 - rn2), Code
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3;
```

### Demo

Note that the reason for using `DISTINCT` above is that, possibly, a given code could appear in an island of 3 *more* than once.  But, your requirement above is that you only want to report a matching code once.

Comment: Fantastic! This does the trick. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Use `lead()`.  To get the first value of a sequence:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(sequential, 2) over (order by sequential) as sequential_2,
             lead(sequential, 2) over (partition by code order by sequential) as sequential_code_2
      from t
     ) t
where sequential_code_2 = sequential_2;
```

If you really just want the codes, use `select distinct code`.